# update a delayed function in javascript

Tags: javascript, function, intervals

I have a simple javascript function that loads on document ready:

```
var start = 1;
var speed = 1000;
    $(document).ready(function () {
        go();
        setInterval(function () {
            go();
        }, speed);
```

This is the function in details:

```
function go() {
    $("#score").html(start.toLocaleString());
    start += 1;
}
```

This is basically a counter which starts from number 1 to infinite, at 1000 milliseconds speed. Here is the thing , now: I have another function:

```
function modify() {
  speed = 500;
}
```

which regulates the `setIntval` speed on the main function. The problem is it applies on page refresh only. How do I update it in real time without refreshing page?

Comment: Just call it `modify()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A really simple solution is to make use of the `setInterval`'s *parameters*,

```
var intervalID = scope.setInterval(func, delay[, param1, param2, ...]);
```

and also pass the `speed` as *param1*.

Then, at each interval, check if it changed, and if, clear the existing timer and fire up a new.

Stack snippet

```js
var start = 1;
var speed = 1000;
var timer;

$(document).ready(function() {
  go();
  timer = setInterval(function(p) {
    go(p);
  }, speed, speed);
  
  // for this demo
  $("button").click(function(){ speed = speed/2});
})

function go(p) {
  if(p && p != speed) {
    clearInterval(timer);
    timer = setInterval(function(p) {
      go(p);
    }, speed, speed);
  }
  
  $("#score").html(start.toLocaleString());
  start += 1;
}
```

```css
div {
   display: inline-block;
   width: 40px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="score">0</div>

<button>Modify</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't update the current one, you have to stop it and set a new timer, which does the same but with a different delay.

```
var speed = 1000;
var start = 1;
function go() {
    $("#score").html(start.toLocaleString());
    start += 1;
}

function startGoTimer(){
  return = setInterval(function () {
      go();
    }, speed);
}

function modifyTimer( previousTimer, newDelay=500) {
    clearInterval(previousTimer);
    speed = newDelay;
    startGoTimer();
}

var timer = startGoTimer();
// Some code
modifyTimer(timer, 500);
```

---

For fun I just tested what would hapopen if you just change the time:

```
var timing = 1000;
var interval = setInterval(function(){console.log("test")}, timing);
// Now we get a log every 1000ms, change the var after some time (via console):
timing = 10;
// still an interval of 1000ms.
```

Comment: Yeah sure. , keep the functions out of it though, combine those into one file